# How to create or refer to animations from scripts in three.js/editor?

Tags: three.js

Have a nice day! I want to ask you - how can I create an animation for a model (or find an existing one created from a 3d editor: Maya, Blender, etc.)? Or how can I refer to it from scripts (that the most important feature for me)? Please, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full animation support in the editor was added with `r123`. Animation clips of a 3D object are now stored in [Object3D.animations](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.animations).

When importing an animated asset via glTF, FBX or Collada, its animations will be stored in the top-level node's `animations` property. E.g. `gltf.scene.animations`.

In the editor, you can access these animations by adding a script to the respective node and then use `this.animations` in the `update()` function.